# Guarantee uint8_t smaller then 9

Tags: c

I would like to guarantee that a unsigned value is smaller then 9 without a branch and without the modulo operator(requirement):
The algorithm with modulo:

```
x  = x % 9
```

The algorithm with a loop/branch:

```
while(x >= 9)
{
  x -= 9;
}
```

In special cases (like threshold == 8), this can be achieved by:

```
x = x & 0x07u;
```

Is there a possibility for a threshold equal to 9?

Comment: So you want to inplement a modulo operator identical to the built-in version but without using one. May I ask you why?

Comment: in fact, i do need a special threshold which is equal to 9 and i would like to know if there exist an efficient solution. I will update my question

Comment: Why can't you just use the modulo operator?

Comment: Use look-up table? It would only require `uint8_t array[256] = { .... }`.

Comment: If an efficient alternative existed, the compiler would use that instead of the modulo instruction. For example, `x%4` will probably be replaced by the compiler with `x&3` if `x` is unsigned.

Comment: We are using c89 and follow the misra-c guidelines. Moreover, this code shall be supported by different compilers and therefore, the modulo operator is implemented differently and can differ concerning negative numbers. This is the reason for omitting him.

Comment: @m47h you stated that the input is unsigned, so negative numbers is not a concern

Comment: @M.M: this is correct, nonetheless the operator should be omitted in our source code

Comment: @m47h Not entirely sure, but I seem to remember that standard library function `div` guarantees consistent remainder sign. You might want to look further into it.

Comment: @user694733: be careful, lookup-tables require memory access. And that is sometimes very sloooooow....

Comment: One trick is to decompose to `x=a*64+b*8+c`, the the problem reduces to `x%9=(a-b+c)%9`, which is worst case `[-7, 10]` range for [0-255] input, which makes loop-up-table highly feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what compilers are for. You enter code that generates the output you want, and the compiler generates the most efficient assembly to produce that output.

In fact the C language is defined in terms of an abstract machine in which only its observable behaviour is defined.

For the program:

```
int main(int x, char **z)
{ 
    x  = x % 9;
    return x;
}
```

gcc 5.2 -O3 generates:

```
main:
    movl    %edi, %eax
    movl    $954437177, %edx
    imull   %edx
    movl    %edx, %eax
    movl    %edi, %edx
    sarl    %eax
    sarl    $31, %edx
    subl    %edx, %eax
    leal    (%rax,%rax,8), %eax
    subl    %eax, %edi
    movl    %edi, %eax
    ret
```

I am not sure exactly what this is, but 954437177 is `0b00111000111000111000111000111001`.  If you are interested perhaps you could benchmark this assembly against anything else that you come up with by hand.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why one would want to replace the modulo operator.
If it is about *efficiency*, consider the following two examples:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int x  = argc % 9;
  return x;
}
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  int x = argc - (argc / 9) * 9;
  return x;
}
```

For both implementation, `gcc -g -O3` is generating the *same assembly* (I am using gcc 4.8.1 on x86):

```
main:
    movl    %edi, %eax  # argc, tmp71
    movl    $954437177, %edx    #, tmp65
    imull   %edx    # tmp65
    movl    %edi, %eax  # argc, tmp67
    sarl    $31, %eax   #, tmp67
    sarl    %edx    # x
    subl    %eax, %edx  # tmp67, x
    leal    (%rdx,%rdx,8), %eax #, tmp70
    subl    %eax, %edi  # tmp70, x
    movl    %edi, %eax  # x,
    ret
```

Conclusion: **don't care about efficiency** (in this case and in the most other cases), let the compiler do that.

BTW: `954437177` is `(2^33 + 1) / 9`

Answer (score 1):

You could use this method, devoid of loop, branch or modulo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t x = 15; 
    printf("%u", x - (x/9)*9);
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
6
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's silly to replace a modulo operation with division, which will be just as slow or slower. They are even implemented with the same instruction on x86.

Comment: @interjay I thought it was one of those student exercises "I am not allowed to..."